# os.popen "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan" returns expected values when run stand-alone, but not under FLASK

Tags: python, linux, flask, subprocess

I'm trying to update my [Raspberry Pi python 3.x app](https://github.com/greiginsydney/Intervalometerator/) to scan for nearby WiFi networks, but I can't get past an impasse with "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan".

It's fine when executed as a standalone script, but when the SAME user runs the same code as a FLASK app, I get errors: either zero output, or the dreaded `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo'`

This free-standing script returns all of the nearby WiFi networks when executed *without* sudo from the command line:

```py
import os
import getpass
import subprocess

output = os.popen("sudo iwlist wlan0 scan").read() # Works beautifully when stand-alone
print(output)

print(f'Effective user is {getpass.getuser()}')
```

Output:

```py
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $ python3 test.py
wlan0     Scan completed :
  Cell 01 - Address: 11:22:BF:21:33:44
            Channel:1
    
<edit>
        
  Cell 10 - Address: 55:55:EB:66:77:25
            Channel:5
<edit> 

Effective user is pi
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $
```

... and yet I have an 'empty' result value when I try the same under flask:

```py
app.logger.debug(f'Effective user is {getpass.getuser()}')
output = os.popen("sudo iwlist wlan0 scan").read()
app.logger.debug(f'SUCCESS: {output}')
```

```py
[2023-11-06 09:49:54 +1100] [3983] [DEBUG] GET /network
[2023-11-06 09:49:55 +1100] [3983] [DEBUG] Effective user is pi
[2023-11-06 09:49:55 +1100] [3983] [DEBUG] SUCCESS:
```

I read suggestions that my FLASK version isn't waiting for a response, so I tried a different approach with subprocess.Popen, with the same disparity in results, and a different failure under FLASK:

```py
import os
import getpass
import subprocess

cmd = ["sudo", "iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"]
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, encoding='utf-8')
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = result.communicate()
if stdoutdata:
    print(stdoutdata.strip())
if stderrdata:
    print(stderrdata.strip())

print(f'Effective user is {getpass.getuser()}')
```

Output:

```py
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $ python3 test2.py
wlan0     Scan completed :
  Cell 01 - Address: 11:22:BF:21:33:44
            Channel:1
    
<edit>
        
  Cell 10 - Address: 55:55:EB:66:77:25
            Channel:5
<edit> 

Effective user is pi
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $
```

... and yet when run from FLASK I get this in return:

```py
[2023-11-09 09:24:45 +1100] [11683] [DEBUG] GET /network
[2023-11-09 09:24:46 +1100] [11683] [DEBUG] Effective user is pi
[2023-11-09 09:24:46 +1100] [11683] [DEBUG] runSubprocess threw: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo'
```

I've tried every alternative I can find on SO. I must be missing something basic & fundamental. Please put me out of my misery.

Comment: Perhaps Flask is running from a different directory and your command is not working because of that? What happens when you print `pwd` from `os.popen` in Flask?

Comment: Side-note: Having a webapp that is *able* to use administrative permissions is like handing a shotgun, a map to your house, and a good time to find you asleep to your local neighborhood serial killer. If `sudo` works without a password, always, then basically any flaw in the webapp is a root-level exploit. I'd almost hope Flask's security features were hiding it from you (even if that is a bit nanny-ish), because it's basically never an appropriate thing to run from a webapp.

Comment: Both a surprise and not a surprise @rabbibillclinton. I get different results with popen and subprocess:

    [DEBUG] Effective user is pi
    [DEBUG] SUCCESS: /home/pi/www

...and this is subprocess:
    [DEBUG] runSubprocess threw: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pwd'

Comment: I take your point @ShadowRanger, but I can't see any other way for a python-based Pi app to query nearby WiFi networks. Would gladly not elevate if there was a way around it...

Comment: @greiginsydney: Could a scheduled job separate from the webapp update the information in a file the webapp reads from? Heck, the webapp could write information to *tell* that scheduled job to run, as long as it doesn't have permissions to launch root level things in general. Something needs the permissions to perform the query (I assume, this is not a thing I've ever done), but it need not, and should not, be the webapp itself.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger, that's an approach I hadn't thought of, but given the time I've invested in this futile effort thus far, it's looking very likely my solution.

Comment: @greiginsydney, it's easy to configure `/etc/sudoers` to only allow _one narrow, specific_ command to be escalated (only when called by a specific user, with specific arguments and specific environment variables), not any and every command. Though you can also typically do something like manage permissions to be able to communicate with the daemon on the other side of `iwlist`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I said when I asked this that I figured the solution was going to be simple. I didn't realise it was THIS simple. @rabbibillclinton was on on the money with their initial response.

It transpires that `sudo` isn't an internal command of the os - it's a program, and when `subprocess.Popen` reported `No such file or directory` it was trying to point that out to me.

```py
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
pi@BenchPi3BPlus:~ $
```

And so the fix was just to add the path to sudo:

```py
cmd = ["/usr/bin/sudo", "iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"]
result = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

(Strangely when I tried this with subprocess.Popen it was still reporting No such file or directory)

@ShadowRanger is correct suggesting I shouldn't be doing this, but this is the answer to the question asked.

A better approach is to turn this request into a systemctl daemon and poke it from Flask, then waitfor and read the response.